# Is this iPhone question in-scope?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

[Suggestions for Kosher iPhone apps](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11824/suggestions-for-kosher-iphone-apps)

Does it make sense for us to host this question? Does it count as a question about JL&L, or is it just a market research question that's specific to this time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems okay to me.

#### Topicality

[The FAQ list](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq) says:

> If you have a question about... general knowledge (science, etc.) as it relates directly to Jewish life and learning... then you've come to the right place.

This seems right on target. Compare: [Latest shabbat not longest day...?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2326)

#### Temporality

The FAQ list says:

> Common reasons a question may be closed include:... This question is unlikely to ever help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet.

Any answer given to this question is relevant forever. Well, until someone writes an app in response to that answer, but possibly forever. And it's relevant to all app writers, which, while not the general public, is a large set of people, not just the asker.

#### And another point

(Sorry, I couldn't think of anything that starts with *t* and ends with *ality*.)

The FAQ list says:

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where... every answer is equally valid: "What's your favorite ______?"

Here, the question isn't so much "what's your favorite X" as "what would be a useful X", with (likely) multiple equally valid answers (but not *all* answers equally valid). in particular, answers can (and, ideally, should) come with explanations of why or how the proposed app would be useful and different from what's already on the market.

Comment: seems to fit the title Jewish life

Comment: I've edited the question to incorporate your closing recommendation.

Comment: Isn't every answer equally valid still?

Comment: @avi, if someone suggests an app that others think is less than useful or that's already on the market, that'd be a poor answer.